# Broken python 3.10 at Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I have tried to update my `Ubuntu` from `20.04` to `22.04` and broken python during command

```
sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.1[01]' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Now I could not use commands as `apt-get update` or `install` with message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: python3.10 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

System has `python3.11` and `python3.10`, but latest one has broken most part of libs as `http` for example. So system is unstable.

Advices like `apt --fix-broken install` falls with messages like "dpkg founded too many errors and stopped" or "no `http` module into python.."

Also I have seen an advice to clean `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file from packages mentioned above, but still no effect.

How could I solve it without full reinstall of 22.04?

Comment: At this point, just reinstalling the OS is probably the best way to go.

Comment: No way to just reinstall `python3.10`?